# How to check if firebase security is well configured to avoid data stealing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How can I make sure my firebase realtime database data is not accessible (read or download) via REST or any other way ?

I am very concerned about this as it seem to be a common way (not to secure properly your database) to steal data from apps.

My nodes all have the same security for reading : authentification required.

Thank you !

Comment: Check firebase security rules ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: Yes I did it and this is why I say in my post that authentification is required to read data. But is there something more to do ? To avoid people downloading data by using curl ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've left the default security rules, which simply require a user to be signed in to be able to read/write all data. While this blocking of unauthenticated users is a good first step, there is probably more you can do.

The Firebase documentation explain [how you can use Firebase's server-side security rules to precisely control what data each user can access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart). I highly recommend also watching the video in there, for a good introduction of what mindset to have while thinking of securing your data in this way.

Comment: In fact, I do think that my security rules are well configured (I followed all the firebase documentation regarding this subject), but I may be wrong. My main concern is that someone who has an account in Firebase Auth could be able to perform a curl request

Comment: If that is a use-case that you want to disallow for your app, then you should modify your security rules to disallow it. The documentation is your best way to get started on that, since it describes how you can ensure only authorized access is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the exact answer I was looking for : if you want to download data that needs authentification with REST, you need a token.

So to sum up : **No, 'simple' users can not download nodes that are protected by security rules, they also need a token that only the admin can generate.**

Please feel free to correct me if all the above is wrong